# PulseSchedule jobs not getting submitted on Pulse enabled machines on IBM Quantum

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, qiskit-runtime

There was a recent migration, referring the below document:
https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-provider/tutorials/Migration_Guide_from_qiskit-ibmq-provider.html

Before this migration, I was using IBMQ for submitting jobs on IBM quantum devices. But after changing the function from IBMQ to IBMProvider, my jobs are failing with the below message:

```
QpyError: "Object type '<class 'qiskit.pulse.schedule.Schedule'>' is not supported in Program namespace."
```

I'm not sure why I'm not able to submit the same jobs on the same machine. I just changed the interface through which I was interacting with IBM quantum backends.